# Querying the DNS service records to find the hostname and TCP/IP

Tags: java, dns, host, bioinformatics

In a paper about the **Life Science Identifiers** (see [LSID Tester, a tool for testing Life Science Identifier resolution services](http://www.scfbm.org/content/3/1/2)), Dr Roderic DM Page wrote :

Given the LSID urn:lsid**:ubio.org**:namebank:11815, querying the DNS for the SRV record for *_lsid._tcp*.**ubio.org** returns animalia.ubio.org:80 as the location of the ubio.org LSID service.

I learned that I can link _lsid._tcp.ubio.org to animalia.ubio.org:80 using the **host** command on unix:

```
host -t srv _lsid._tcp.ubio.org
_lsid._tcp.ubio.org has SRV record 1 0 80 ANIMALIA.ubio.org
```

How can I do this 'DNS' thing using the Java J2SE API (Without any external java library, I'd like a lightweight solution ) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The JNDI DNS provider can lookup SRV records.  You need to do something like:

```
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory");
env.put("java.naming.provider.url", "dns:");
DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
Attributes attrs = ctx.getAttributes("_lsid._tcp.ubio.org", new String[] { "SRV" });
```

The returned attributes are an enumeration of strings that look like "1 0 80 ANIMALIA.ubio.org".  The space separated fields are in order:

1. priority
2. weight
3. port
4. server

Comment: Thanks ! Looks interesting ! I will test your solution later in the WE. :-)

Comment: I know it's quite old, but I would like to note on `line 4` that `this.env` should be `env`. +1 For good answer though, just what I needed. <3

Answer (score 11):

You can't do this using the standard Java libraries.  The `InetAddress` class is only capable of looking up DNS `A` records.

To look up `SRV` records (and indeed any other DNS resource record type other than an `A` record) you need a third party library.  [`dnsjava`](http://www.dnsjava.org/) is the usual option.

I've personally used the 1.6 version on Google Android, it works fine.  Version 2.0 and later use the Java `nio` layer, so won't be compatible with earlier JVMs.

Comment: Hello, I am trying to integrate dnsjava-1.6.6 into my android app in order to do SRV resolution. I wonder, did you compile the entire dnsjava package and pull in the .jar - or did you extract the relevant source files from the package.... to keep it lightweight?

Thanks!

Comment: in my case I've just added the whole (pre-compiled) .jar file to my project.  It should be feasible to only add in the files you need, though.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't do it without using some external libraries. [java.util.InetAddress](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html) has some methods to resolve names via DNS, but it's only usable for resolving names into IP addresses and not for generic DNS querying.

For that, you need some external library like [DNSJava](http://www.dnsjava.org/).

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody is looking for non-Java solutions (which they might given that the title of the question isn't language specific), when I implemented a LSID (see [doi:10.1186/1751-0473-3-2](http://dx.doi.org/10.1186/1751-0473-3-2)) I used the PEAR package [Net_DNS](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_DNS), which can look up SRV records.

Comment: Alternatively, make a self-answered question to share your work. :)